# How do I identify if, out of three groups, two are more similar to each other than the other, with statistical support, in R

Tags: r, distributions, biostatistics, similarities

I have seen similar questions but I believe there are some differences in what I wish to do. I have three groups, A,B, and C. I have two variables namely

1. matings,
2. feather reflectance

for all the individuals in each group. The sample sizes are not equal and matings and reflectances are non-normally distributed. The three groups are different experimental treatments and it is not a repeated measures design as all recordings are done at once across the treatments. I expect a trend in the matings such that C>B>A, and for reflectance either 1) C=B>A or 2)C>B>>A

Is there a way that I can test/prove if group B is an intermediate group in both matings and reflectance simultaneously? That is, it is not a subset of either A or C but is truly a unique group?

I've heard about linear discriminant analysis (LDA) but I'm unable to find non-parametric versions of it or if it truly answers the question.

I work with R mainly and would appreciate links/codes/packages in R.

Comment: what is the nature of your variables 1 and 2? are they continuous? discrete? ordered? bounded? measured with error?

Comment: The simplest answer will probably be to start off with some kind of appropriate linear regression

Comment: The matings are counts, essentially discrete. Reflectance is continuous. As per my understanding, linear regressions are used with mainly normal data??

Comment: 1) normality of the outcome is not required, normality of the residuals is (in order for inference to be correct) 2) I was thinking Generalized linear regression would probably be more appropriate if your outcome is not continuous. Sounds like a Poisson regression would be appropriate for mating and maybe a normal linear regression for reflectance maybe with a log link if it is very skewed.